# MATLAB's system function and the PowerShell call operator (&)

Tags: powershell, matlab

When I try to use the call operator in MATLAB's `system` function I get an error.  For example, this command works just fine in PowerShell:

```
& "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv"
```

but in MATLAB this does not work:

```matlab
system('& "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv"')
```

and I get the error `& was unexpected at this time.`  It looks like a PowerShell error since  MATLAB doesn't actually return an error.  But it is clear that the command is not running correctly as it does when I just run it correctly in powershell.

Comment: `system` runs the command in a regular shell (`cmd.exe`), not in PowerShell.

Comment: The correct way would be to set the ampersand last.
`system('"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv" &')`

Comment: Note that if you really want to run a PowerShell command then `system( 'powershell -command "whatever you need to run here"' );`

Answer (score 0):

As [Cris Luengo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7328782/cris-luengo) pointed out, MATLAB's `system` uses `cmd.exe`, not PowerShell.  So this works:

```matlab
system('"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv" myProject.sln /Build')
```

And indeed it was building the solution, but not displaying any output of the build or giving the correct return value on whether the build failed or was successful.  [Aero Engy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1106634/aero-engy)'s suggestion of using `powershell -command` at the beginning of the call also works, and even better, it returns the correct value and the output of the build is displayed in the console.  Had to escape some spaces with backticks (couldn't figure out the nested quotes otherwise) but this is now my preferred solution:

```matlab
system('powershell -Command "& C:\Program` Files\Microsoft` Visual` Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv myProject.sln /Build"')
```